# PyCharm file path separator

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter, filepath

I was evaluating PyCharm with one of my script and went into a problem directly at first line.
In my script I do this:

```py
filename =  './trial/{0}'.format(sys.argv[0].split('\\')[-1].replace(".py",""))
```

Splitting with `"\\"` worked everytime on the command prompt (I'm working on Windows)

If I run/debug in PyCharm the `"\\"` split doesn't work, I've seen the file is launched by the interpreter as:

```
"C:\Python26\python.exe C:/Users/nboldri/Desktop/..."
```

so it gets as separator `"/"` and split function doesn't work with `"\\"`

Is there a way in PyCharm to pass the filepath to the interpreter in the windows format with backslash? I've searched but couldn't find anything in settings or internet.

Comment: Why don't you use the `os.path` functions for this?

Comment: I know that could be a solution and also a more correct code implementation but I've several scripts that use same logic and sincerely I didn't like to change everything for just an IDE trifle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the file name and removing the extension.

Use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), which returns the file path and its extension, and [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to get the filename:

```
import os
import sys

filename, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
trialname = './trial/{0}'.format(filename)
```

If this is used in lots of places in your code, replace it with a function:

```
def filename_with_no_extension(filepath):
    from os.path import splitext, basename        
    return splitext(basename(filepath))
```

Then:

```
import sys
trialname = './trial/{0}'.format(filename_with_no_extension(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'd like to find a way to "fix" pycharm way to send the path instead that act on the code. Is it possible?

Comment: PyCharm is [open source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/python), so you could [log a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY), and submit a patch. However, I don't think PyCharm is really 'broken', so it probably won't get accepted.

Comment: There is already [an issue raised](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9535), although it's been there since 17 Apr 2013.

Comment: I think I'll signup and add a comment that the issue is not only a cosmetic one but also a functional issue, maybe it raises the priority.